# Memory management of View Controllers

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am creating view controllers that hold some information to display(image, buttons, gestures, text, etc) and adding them to a scroll.

```
productsVCs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= [self.products count]; i++) {
    productsSingle *single = [[productosSingle alloc] init];
    single.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 148);
    single.delegate = self;
    [single setInfo:[self.products objectAtIndex:i-1]];
    [scroll addSubview:single.view];
    [productsVCs addObject:single];
}
```

As you can see, I'm doing three important things with these view controllers I'm allocating, I wrote what I think is needed to have ARC release these objects.

1) Set the delegate. -Do I have to set the delegate to nil?

2) Add the view as a subview. -Remove from superview?

3) Add the controller to an array. -Remove from the array?

My question is, when are these view controllers deallocated? Using ARC. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The object `productsSingle`will be deallocated when your ViewController (that have the scroll view) will be deallocated.

ARC works at compile-time, and so ARC inserts for you the calls to `release` method on your objects. When you will compile the project, ARC insert the the calls to `release` method like this:

```
[single setInfo:[self.products objectAtIndex:i-1]];
[scroll addSubview:single.view];
[single release]; //ARC inserts this line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC you don't have to worry about releasing your objects since ARC will do it for you. Still you can set up strongly held instance variables in your controllers to be released in your `viewDidUnload` method.

Now, your view controllers will be deallocated when whatever is holding the reference to them is deallocated, in this case it would be the application itself or another controller that created the controller. If you don't hold a reference to it, it will get deallocated as soon as you exit the code block though.

[Here's a little guide on using ARC](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-5-automatic-reference-counting-arc)

Comment: What if "whatever is holding the reference" which I guess would be my viewController, doesn't get deallocated. Let's say it's my main view and I just dynamically load these view controllers and when there's new info available I want them removed and do this cycle again. Hope you understood what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: You asked about allocating view controllers, so that's what I said whatever was holding them. You mean you are just replacing these elements on the view when you have new data and refresh what you're showing? If you hold instance variables to these view elements they will go away, objects only exist in the local scope if no reference is held on them. If you're replacing the elements you add to the view, you'll have to nil them out of you replace all of them, as to avoid overloading the memory.

Comment: You could do it by holding that array as an ivar and them calling removeFromSuperview on the view elements. Or iterate over the subviews array of the view and remove the views that match your productosSingle class.